# Create table for each id existent in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is a way to create a MySQL table for each ID that exists in another table. I think that would be fairly easy doing it with PHP, but I'm not sure if that can be done with MySQL.

So for instance I have a table called `users` which has an X amount of columns. One column is the IDs column. So I would like to iterate through that column and grab the IDs and create for each of those IDs a new table which will have the name of `"user_specific_id_ " + ID`. So for the ID `1` the name of the newly created table would be `user_specific_id_1`.

Could the above be done just with MySQL, or is it necessary to use PHP ? And if I need to use PHP what would be the approach ?

Comment: Use MySQl trigger to generate a new table after insertion of row in users table

Comment: While possible, this sounds like a really bad design...

Comment: I just realized that, and I decided not to do that and just have a table with all the things that will be user specific and have the same ID on rows as the users table has, and when I'll operate on the tables the users will have the same id on both ones :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a pure MySQL way. Using PHP you'll select all id's from your table, and then in a `foreach` loop issue a `CREATE TABLE user_specific_id + $id` query

That being said, creating a separate table for each user doesn't sound like the correct way of handling a DB.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an awfully bad idea.

It is a bad idea because you cannot decently JOIN the tables using mysql.

Instead of a table for each user, consider having a table with a multi-column primary key for all users.

You can, of course do what you described with PHP, for example using PDO.